# Can a Java application server (WebLogic) manage a native executable?

Tags: glassfish, weblogic, native, failover

Is it possible (...knowing full well that this is crazy and seriously ill-advised...) to have a J2EE application running in a Java app server (using weblogic presently), and have a native executable process started, used, and stopped as part of this Java application's lifecycle?  (Note: this is *not* JNI, it's actually a separate native process. It's unix/linux, but should also run on windows.)  I haven't found any docs on the subject -- and for good reason, probably.

Background: The native process is actually some monolithic 3rd party software package that is un-hackable and there's no API other than stdin/stdout. The Java app requires the native app to perform certain services.  I can easily wrap the native process via ProcessBuilder and start/stop and communicate with it (using stdin/stdout).  For testing purposes I have a simple exe (C++) that communicates via stdin/stdout and can receive "start", "shutdown" and performs a simple "echo" service. (The "start" is a no-op, but simply returns "ok" if the native process started successfully.)

So, ideally, when the app server is started/shutdown, and/or the deployed Java app is started/shutdown, the associated native process can also be started/shutdown.  And ideally, this can happen cleanly & reliably (no lingering processes after shutdown, all startup failures logged, the lifecycle timing issues synchronized).

If this actually worked, then "part 2" of the question would be if this could actually work in a cluster/failover environment.  The native process could be tied to a platform and software-specific monitoring & management service, but I'd like to have everything bundled and managed with the Java app, if possible.

If Glassfish or any other OSGi type environment would make this simpler, please feel free to let me know (it *could* be an option... I'd prefer Glassfish, but WLS is the blanket mandate.)

I'm trying to put together a proof-of-concept, but any clear answer "yes, I've done it" or "no, it won't work" would be much appreciated & a huge time-saver (with supporting doc links, if you have them).

Edit: just to clarify (the subject may be misleading): there is a considerable Java application running as well (which I've written & can freely modify as necessary); the 3rd party native process just performs a service that the Java application requires. I'm not merely trying to manage a native process via an app server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to part 1 is yes, it is absolutely possible to have a Java application server manage a native system process.  It sounds like you've pretty much figured this out for yourself, if you're thinking about using a `ProcessBuilder` to spawn the external program and interact with it.  That's pretty much the way to do it.

I have used exactly that kind of setup in the past to implement a media transcoding service on top of a Java server (the Java server spawned transcoding jobs via ffmpeg processes, monitoring their status and reporting back to the rest of the application on success/failure/etc.).  How cleanly it can all be done depends upon how you implement it and upon the behavior of your external app (i.e. is it guaranteed to respond gracefully and quickly to a shutdown request?), but it will be very difficult (if not impossible) to get it completely perfect.  At a minimum, if someone does a `kill -9` on your Java server process, there is no way for you to gracefully shut down the native process, at least not until the server is restarted and you see that the native process is already running.

The second part depends upon exactly what you mean by "work in a cluster/failover environment".  In terms of managing the native process, if you can start it and interact with it in Java then you can also manage it in Java.  But if you mean you want perfect failover behavior such that if the node with the native process on it goes down then a new node automatically resumes the process *in the exact same state as it was before*, then that may be very difficult or even impossible.  But, if you abstract out interactions with the external process so that it just appears as a service that your Java code interacts with (for instance, perhaps by sending requests to some facade class that understands how to interact with and manage the external process) then you should be able to get some fairly good results.

The transcoding service that I implemented ran in a clustered environment (using JBoss/Tomcat), and the way it worked was that when a transcoding job was requested a message would be dispatched.  This message would be received by a coordinating class that would manage the queue of transcode requests, spawning jobs as worker processes became available.  The state of the queue was replicated across the cluster, so if the node running the ffmpeg processes went down the currently scheduled jobs would be remembered, and then resumed as soon as a suitable node was available again (the transcoding service was configurable so that it could be enabled/disabled per node).  In practice the system proved to be quite robust.

Comment: Thanks.  The replicated work-request queue is a good & simple idea.